# How do I restore my project to an older version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not using subversion or something like this, only Android Studio. I messed up some features and I need to get back to an older version of the project

How do I do it?

Comment: Thanks for your ironic answer. Did you mean that it cannot be turned back to an older version if I use only Android Studio?

Comment: I am also facing such a problem. What I want is just to restore to previous commit, but find no way to do that in simple way

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Right click on a class file, and select "Local History". This will also work on directories.

[image: Show Local History on App module directory]

Comment: this is not about the whole project

Comment: @tainy I don't understand what you mean. You can select any folder in the browser and check the Local History (i.e. the `app` directory), it doesn't just have to be a Class file.

Comment: Thanks for explain. I did not know that we can show the history of a folder. So please edit the answer for better understanding:-)

Comment: you saved my life!

Comment: can I get 3 days old project

Comment: @AhmadArslan - Probably not, unless it's in your local history of backed up somewhere else. You should start using some form of Version Control :)

Comment: I want to give you 100 votes for this help. Thank you so much @PPartisan

Answer (score 5):

Switch view to `Android` in the left part of the Android Studio, right-click the `app` node, `Local History`, `Show History`. Then find the revision you want back, right click it and choose `Revert`. Your whole project will be reverted to this state.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `Project` in the left part of Android Studio, right-click the `application name` on top, click `Local History`, click `Show History`.

Then find the revision you want back, right click it and choose `Revert`. Your whole project will be reverted to this state.

Another solution here suggested Switch to Android in the left menu before reverting but that **will not revert the entire project**. I failed using that solution.