# Android Studio: Restore Project Backup after Gradle Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After opening an older project for the first time after a few weeks/months (very busy with work) Android Studio asked me to upgrade to the latest gradle plugin.

[Gradle Upgrade promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSmBy.png)

I didn't really think anything of it and hit "Update". After Gradle finished updating and syncing I noticed that most of my layout and java class files vanished. They're simply gone.

However, in my project's directory a folder called "projectFilesBackup" appeared. I assume that restoring the backup contained in this folder might bring my missing files back.

[projectFilesBackup Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpRVG.png)

So my question is: Does anyone know how I actually tell Android Studio to restore to the backup? It only contains an ".idea" folder which contains "workspace.xml". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already tried using "Local History" to undo any changes done on the day of the Gradle Update as detailed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883232/how-do-i-restore-my-project-to-an-older-version-in-android-studio).

**Edit**:
As requested my build.gradle files:

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tools.awesome.cs.grademanager"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Post both of your build.gradle file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited the files into my original post.

Comment: Your build.gradle file config looks alright to me. If you initiate a gradle sync what does it say?

Comment: Syncing works just fine:
1:42:46 PM Gradle sync started
1:43:33 PM Gradle sync completed.

Rebuilding doesn't because of all the missing files... Any idea how to use the backup it created?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change the realm-gradle-plugin to the most dated one and see if it brings up the files again.

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. Thank you for trying, though!

Comment: I have one of my project gradle plugin updated couple minutes ago and it went fine. In my experience, this update would only cause trouble when the dependencies not meet. Try tinkering with your existing dependencies a little. It might solve your issue.