# How to revert back to old code after pull

Tags: android, git

hope you are having a good day.
I want to know a small thing about pull/push in git repo.

Below is the representation of my code/project.

[image]

**Blue**: This is my code which is worked on and without commit i pulled  the red code from git.
**Red**: This is the older version of blue code.
**Yellow**: this is the code which i have now

So i have worked on blue code but without commit or push i pulled red code, so it over writes my blue updated code and merged as yellow code. So now i want to get back my blue code, is it possible? i searched in my project folder but i cant find it. i search on my git branch code too but it wasn't there too.

Thanks for the read, if you know how to revert that pull request it will save my couple of hours. Thanks again
And by the way this is an android project and code is in bitbucket.

[UPDATE] - Solved-
Thanks for the response. I got my blue code back using Android Studio Local History tool. Reverted all the changes that i have made.

Comment: what is the starting point of your blue code? the tip of the red branch? and what do you mean pulled the red branch? because when you have modification on your current branch when you try loading another branch, git automatically force you to commit. When you pull another branch, what is the option checked in the pull dialog. if i remember you must have something like "with rebase", "merge" and so on

Comment: @FranckNgako,  yes. Blue code is updated version of red. but when i pulled red all my changes of  blue code updated with old red code.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer in the answer section below rather than editing your question with the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git lola9` (if you've set up the alias, or whatever way you prefer to view your commit history), and you should see the commits you pulled. Alternatively, the console output of the `git pull` should also include the commits you pulled.

Once you have that, what I would do is:

1. Note the number of commits you want to git rid of
2. `git stash` your changes,
3. `git reset head~n`, where n is the number of commits we figured out earlier. This will 'un-commit' the changes you pulled
4. `git co .` & `git reset` as needed to 'lose' all those now un-commit-ed changes that you've pulled down
5. `git stash apply` to retrieve your changes (rather than `pop` in case somethings gone wrong, you don't want to dirty your changes)

Comment: I didnt commit my code before pulling, i search my problem and found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883405/6764161) and i found my code their i will try to revert that

Comment: how did you manage to checkout the red branch without committing you work on blue branch? git should have forbidden that. Are you using command lines or something? If it didn't crash maybe git did a silent commit. try looking if there are existing commit on your blue branch. if there is one, then it's your work

Comment: no it just pulled the red code with any conflit. and then i realized that my blue code is deleted..

Comment: I understand you didn't commit your code prior to pulling (I read the question). But your work should still be on top of your branch as un-commited. Are you saying it is somehow gone and your `git status` shows no outstanding changes?

Comment: After spending some time i somehow got my blue code back. i used local history and revert my changes. thankyou.