# Android Studio Shows error in everything suddenly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[See Images.Check Error Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4HqI.png)

I dont know what happened but every thing shows in error. while restarting sometimes it says something like "can not load settings from file android studio". As you can see my, java code turned in to XML code. I am new in Android studio so please someone help me. I cant even go back to my previous version since i forget commit last 24 hour work. Any suggestion and help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the original files content is also the same as that? or in the android studio the files displaying like this?

Comment: No original files were correct but suddenly android studio acting weird. my java code turned in to xml code. Android studio displaying xml code in instead of java code.

Comment: Why is this tagged under `javascript`? Anyway, you probably just copy-pasted something incorrectly. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883232/how-do-i-restore-my-project-to-an-older-version-in-android-studio/29883405#29883405) to see whether you can undo your change

Comment: Thanks bro. I did that but didn't worked. :(

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175409/android-studio-java-file-gets-corrupted/41651518

Comment: No problem... Happy Coding :)

Comment: You can't use imageView in layer-list.

Comment: Two show images, you have to use <item/> tag and set background in item tag